# Is there a way to enqueue a style sheet if a particular template part is loaded?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

There is a template part called 'theme-section-1.php', and a css file called 'theme-section-1.css'.
I want to load the css file only if 'theme-section-1.php' is called. an if/else statement loads the template which is controlled by a checkbox in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by :

```php
$checkbox = true; // Fetch the value of checkbox from database.

if ( $checkbox ) {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
```

> References:
>
> - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 0):

`is_page_template()` does exactly that

```
if (is_page_template('path/to/template.php')) {
    // enqueue style
}
```

The `path/to/template` starts from your theme directory